# how to run an .exe and pass another url as param in java

Tags: java, windows, url, cmd, processbuilder

I want to run an exe file and pass to it an URL as parameter :

```
String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/c", "C:/Program Files/eMailer/myProg.exe", "C:\\Program Files\\eMailer\\params.txt" };
            ProcessBuilder builder= new ProcessBuilder(command);
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = builder.start();
```

the problem here is that I get : 'C:/'Program' is not recognized as command;
when I use `myurl` already not work , I've tried a lot of variations with no result.

NB: I have 2 problems :

1. first with introducing the space in "Program files"
2. second with passing the second URL as parameter for the exe file

Thank you for your help

Comment: i've resolved the problem using **c:\PROGRA~1** (the short name notation of c:\Programme Files) , but if you have another solutions please share it with us , just for knowledge ;) .

Comment: Paths with spaces when passed as an argument to cmd must be quoted `"\"C:/Program Files/eMailer/myProg.exe\""`

Comment: i've tried it with double quote , and another time with single quote but without success

Answer (score 0):

You could try to quote the argument. Otherwise the space in the argument will make `myProg` think there are two arguments.

```
String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/c", "C:/Program Files/eMailer/myProg.exe", "\"C:\\Program Files\\eMailer\\params.txt\"" };
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();
```